# Efficient way to download content of multiple git items via VSTS REST Client Side API

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I have a collection of 400 items that I can download from the repository using the VSTS REST Client Side API.

However I don't understand why i have to make 2nd call to get the content of the item? What is the reason behind this?

Is there a way for my code to be efficient when downloading the content?

Here is the below code:

```
.. code here to set up the connection etc..

//get the items
var gitItems = gitClient.GetItemsAsync(repo.Id, scopePath: "/DemoWebApp/Source/DemoTests/",
    download: false, includeContentMetadata: true, includeLinks: true, recursionLevel: VersionControlRecursionType.Full).Result.Where(x => x.IsFolder == false);

foreach(var gitItem in gitItems)
{
    var gitItemUrl = gitItem.Url.Split('?')[0];

    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(gitItemUrl);

    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(gitItem.Path);
    var directoryInfo = fileInfo.Directory;
    var subDirectory = directoryInfo.Name;

    //get the item's content which is a Stream
    var itemContent = gitClient.GetItemContentAsync(repo.Id.ToString(), gitItem.Path).Result;

    //working directory where to store the files.
    var workingDirectory = string.Format("C:\\Download\\{0}", subDirectory);

    //only create the directory if it doesnt exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(workingDirectory))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(workingDirectory);
    }

    //Actually process the files and generate the output
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(string.Format(workingDirectory + "\\{0}",fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        itemContent.CopyTo(fileStream);
        itemContent.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`GetItemsAsync()` methed cannot get content of the items and it does not have "includeContent" parameter either.

If you want to download the items, use `GetItemZipAsync()` method. It will download all the items under the path you specified as a zip on your machine.

```
        Stream res = ghc.GetItemZipAsync("RepoId", "Path").Result;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(string.Format(@"D:\a\1.zip"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            res.CopyTo(fs);
            res.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/items/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1

URI Parameters
includeContent

boolean

Set to true to include item content when requesting json. Default is false.